Building Kernel - Invalid Symbol Value
I'm building a customized OpenWRT image for a Teltonika RUT241 Modem/Router. My build is based off the 'SDK' from the manufacturer with a few extra addons.
When I build it on my local development PC (under Ubuntu 22.04 in a VirtualBox), I have no issues (or at least, the build succeeds and gives me a new FW image to flash to the device & test).
But when I try to run the same build in an Ubuntu 22.04 image in an Azure DevOps Pipeline on my server, the build fails with .config:4645:warning: symbol value 'm' invalid for NF_CT_PROTO_GRE and then goes into 'interactive' config mode and gets stuck waiting for user input at Ralink I2C Controller (I2C_RALINK) [N/m/y/?] (NEW).
I have my own local 'mirror' of the 'SDK' with my addons stored in a private git repo, and I am 100% certain that my local build and the DevOps pipeline are both using the same commit on the same branch in that repo.
Can anyone give me any hints as to what might be triggering this behavior in my pipeline build, but not in my local build?
The logs leading up to the condition look like this:
  bash ./scripts/headers_install.sh arch/mips/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_o32.h usr/include/asm/unistd_o32.h
  bash ./scripts/headers_install.sh arch/mips/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_n32.h usr/include/asm/unistd_n32.h
  bash ./scripts/headers_install.sh arch/mips/include/generated/uapi/asm/bpf_perf_event.h usr/include/asm/bpf_perf_event.h
  bash ./scripts/headers_install.sh arch/mips/include/generated/uapi/asm/ipcbuf.h usr/include/asm/ipcbuf.h
  bash ./scripts/headers_install.sh arch/mips/include/generated/uapi/asm/kvm_para.h usr/include/asm/kvm_para.h
  bash ./scripts/headers_install.sh arch/mips/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_n64.h usr/include/asm/unistd_n64.h
  mkdir -p /__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/linux-ramips_mt76x8/linux-5.15.149/user_headers; rsync -mrl --include='*/' --include='*\.h' --exclude='*' usr/include /__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/linux-ramips_mt76x8/linux-5.15.149/user_headers
make[5]: Leaving directory '/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/linux-ramips_mt76x8/linux-5.15.149'
grep '=[ym]' /__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/linux-ramips_mt76x8/linux-5.15.149/.config.set | LC_ALL=C sort | /__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/bin/mkhash md5 > /__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/linux-ramips_mt76x8/linux-5.15.149/.vermagic
touch /__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/linux-ramips_mt76x8/linux-5.15.149/.configured
rm -f /__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/linux-ramips_mt76x8/linux-5.15.149/vmlinux /__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/linux-ramips_mt76x8/linux-5.15.149/System.map
make -C /__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/linux-ramips_mt76x8/linux-5.15.149 KCFLAGS="-fmacro-prefix-map=/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl=target-mipsel_24kc_musl -fno-caller-saves " HOSTCFLAGS="-O2 -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes" CROSS_COMPILE="mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl-" ARCH="mips" KBUILD_HAVE_NLS=no KBUILD_BUILD_USER="" KBUILD_BUILD_HOST="" KBUILD_BUILD_TIMESTAMP="Tue Jun 18 05:31:28 2024" KBUILD_BUILD_VERSION="0" HOST_LOADLIBES="-L/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/lib" KBUILD_HOSTLDLIBS="-L/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/lib" CONFIG_SHELL="bash" V=1  cmd_syscalls=  KERNELRELEASE=5.15.149 CC="mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc" all modules
make[5]: Entering directory '/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/build_dir/target-mipsel_24kc_musl/linux-ramips_mt76x8/linux-5.15.149'
: "  SYNC    include/config/auto.conf.cmd"
make -f ./Makefile syncconfig
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/basic
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=scripts/kconfig syncconfig
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,scripts/kconfig/.conf.o.d -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -std=gnu11 -Wdeclaration-after-statement  -O2 -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes   -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -c -o scripts/kconfig/conf.o scripts/kconfig/conf.c
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,scripts/kconfig/.confdata.o.d -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -std=gnu11 -Wdeclaration-after-statement  -O2 -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes   -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -c -o scripts/kconfig/confdata.o scripts/kconfig/confdata.c
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,scripts/kconfig/.expr.o.d -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -std=gnu11 -Wdeclaration-after-statement  -O2 -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes   -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -c -o scripts/kconfig/expr.o scripts/kconfig/expr.c
  flex -oscripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c -L scripts/kconfig/lexer.l
  bison -o scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.c --defines=scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.h -t -l scripts/kconfig/parser.y
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,scripts/kconfig/.lexer.lex.o.d -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -std=gnu11 -Wdeclaration-after-statement  -O2 -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes   -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include -I ./scripts/kconfig -c -o scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.o scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,scripts/kconfig/.menu.o.d -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -std=gnu11 -Wdeclaration-after-statement  -O2 -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes   -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -c -o scripts/kconfig/menu.o scripts/kconfig/menu.c
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,scripts/kconfig/.parser.tab.o.d -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -std=gnu11 -Wdeclaration-after-statement  -O2 -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes   -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include -I ./scripts/kconfig -c -o scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.o scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.c
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,scripts/kconfig/.preprocess.o.d -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -std=gnu11 -Wdeclaration-after-statement  -O2 -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes   -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -c -o scripts/kconfig/preprocess.o scripts/kconfig/preprocess.c
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,scripts/kconfig/.symbol.o.d -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -std=gnu11 -Wdeclaration-after-statement  -O2 -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes   -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -c -o scripts/kconfig/symbol.o scripts/kconfig/symbol.c
  gcc -Wp,-MMD,scripts/kconfig/.util.o.d -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -std=gnu11 -Wdeclaration-after-statement  -O2 -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes   -I/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/include  -c -o scripts/kconfig/util.o scripts/kconfig/util.c
  gcc   -o scripts/kconfig/conf scripts/kconfig/conf.o scripts/kconfig/confdata.o scripts/kconfig/expr.o scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.o scripts/kconfig/menu.o scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.o scripts/kconfig/preprocess.o scripts/kconfig/symbol.o scripts/kconfig/util.o -L/__w/1/s/mirror-sdk-teltonika-rut241/staging_dir/host/lib 
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
.config:4645:warning: symbol value 'm' invalid for NF_CT_PROTO_GRE
*
* Restart config...
*
*
* I2C Hardware Bus support
*
*
* I2C system bus drivers (mostly embedded / system-on-chip)
*
CBUS I2C driver (I2C_CBUS_GPIO) [N/m/y/?] n
Synopsys DesignWare Platform (I2C_DESIGNWARE_PLATFORM) [N/m/y/?] n
EMMA Mobile series I2C adapter (I2C_EMEV2) [N/m/y/?] n
GPIO-based bitbanging I2C (I2C_GPIO) [N/m/y/?] n
Imagination Technologies I2C SCB Controller (I2C_IMG) [N/m/y/?] n
JZ4780 I2C controller interface support (I2C_JZ4780) [N/m/y/?] n
MT7621/MT7628 I2C Controller (I2C_MT7621) [Y/n/m/?] y
OpenCores I2C Controller (I2C_OCORES) [N/m/y/?] n
PCA9564/PCA9665 as platform device (I2C_PCA_PLATFORM) [N/m/y/?] n
Rockchip RK3xxx I2C adapter (I2C_RK3X) [N/m/y/?] n
Ralink I2C Controller (I2C_RALINK) [N/m/y/?] (NEW) 



NF_CT_PROTO_GRE is a config entry which is defined as a bool, that is, it can only be yes or no.
For some reason, you have managed to configure it as a module.
From 6.10.3, the section is defined in net/netfilter/Kconfig as:
Symbol: NF_CT_PROTO_GRE [=y]
Type  : bool
Defined at net/netfilter/Kconfig:208
  Depends on: NET [=y] && INET [=y] && NETFILTER [=y] && NF_CONNTRACK [=m]
Selected by [m]:
  - NF_CONNTRACK_PPTP [=m] && NET [=y] && INET [=y] && NETFILTER [=y] && NF_CONNTRACK [=m] && NETFILTER_ADVANCED [=y]

It does not appear to be user modifiable, and is set automatically.
It may be possible to just edit the .config file & change the setting for CONFIG_NF_CT_PROTO_GRE from m to y.
Alternatively, it looks like your source has issues & you may have to take a diff between the manufacturers code & pristine release of the kernel and mangle the diff correctly into whichever source you are using.
